# automatic response to cpanm prompt

Tags: perl, module, prompt, cpanm

I am installing perl module [`Bio::DB::Sam`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::DB::Sam).

Shortly, installer asks me to locate `bam.h` and `libbam.a` files:

```
--> Working on Bio::DB::Sam
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/Bio-SamTools-1.39.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Bio-SamTools-1.39 ... Please enter the location of the bam.h and compiled libbam.a files:
```

I know where these files are beforehand and I would like to automatize the process. Something like:

```
echo "/Users/al/programs/samtools-0.1.19" | cpanm Bio::DB::Sam
```

or

```
echo "/Users/alice/programs/samtools-0.1.19" | xargs cpanm Bio::DB::Sam
```

Basically, I want to install this module without any interaction with user. Thanks for suggestions. Everything I have tried so far still asks for location of these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `SAMTOOLS` environment variable to specify a location. See the [Build.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/LDS/Bio-SamTools-1.39/Build.PL#L70) file that handles the module's installation.

Comment: Excellent! You made my day. I exported SAMTOOLS variable and installation went successfully without prompting.